# Damaged package during installation apk

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I generate unsigned apk of my app (school project) and I wanted to try it on my phone. When I download it and start install it, I got error message about package is damaged and application was not installed. Can you tell me what is wrong with it? I do not have idea. Thanks

**SOLUTION:**
I SOLVE THIS BY ADDING KEYSTORE FILE!!

Comment: This seems like a bad sign configuration. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711233/signing-an-existing-apk-using-debug-keystore-generated-by-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

you use android studio so you can run it on your phone by wire conection or if you want to just test your app you can run it on virtual machine.
if you want to release it, its better to first sign it.